# Retrieve an element after a document.on(...) call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm attempting to work with a `document.on()` method, and I need access to the selector element, but it doesn't seem to want to grab the one I intend.

In my HTML, I have this:

```
<td class="dataPickerIconDiv">
   <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down tableIcon dataPickerIcon" aria-hidden="true"                                   
    title="Click to view this table in the Workspace for your project"                                url='/projectworkspace/dataViewer/myRow'></i>
</td>
```

And in my main.js file, located externally, I have this AJAX call to grab a dynamically loaded page from the server:

```
$(document).on('click', '.dataPickerIconDiv', function() {
    console.log($(this))
    var targetArea = $(this).next("i");
    console.log(targetArea)
    var urlToPass = $(targetArea).attr('url');
    console.log("url retrieved: " + urlToPass)
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            $("#projectDataContent").prepend(this.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", urlToPass, true);
    xhttp.send();
});
```

Here's the expanded console output:

```
[td.dataPickerIconDiv]
0 :td.dataPickerIconDiv
length:1
__proto__ : Object(0)
__________________________________ 
[prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]
length:0
prevObject:[td.dataPickerIconDiv]
__proto__ : Object(0)
__________________________________
url retrieved: undefined
```

However, in my console, it's telling my that `urlToPass` is undefined, as it cannot grab the url out of the `targetarea` var. It seems to only define targetarea as a prevObject. How can I grab the url value from the  which follows from the targeted element in the original `click` listener?

Comment: When logging jQuery objects, it's important to look at the `length` property. In your log of `targetArea`, you can see that its `length` is 0. That means no elements were matched by the function you called. See Jason's answer for how to fix.

Comment: that's not now [.next](http://api.jquery.com/next) works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) selects siblings. The `i` is a child of the `td`, not a sibling. Try [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) or [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) instead.

Answer (score -1):

You can invoke the `find()` function on the parent and retrieve the url value by invoking the `attr()` function.

Something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.dataPickerIconDiv', function() {
    var urlToPass = $(this).find('i').attr('url');    
    console.log("url retrieved: " + urlToPass)
});
```

You can check this [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vh191e4w/1/).